# Import FirebaseOSX SDK into a Mac application

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, firebase

I want to create an App with the FirebaseOSX SDK.

I've already installed the pod.

But how do I integrate it into X-Code?

```
import Firebase
```

This gives me an error

```
import FirebaseOSX
```

And this gives me an error too.
I searched a lot on the firebase.com website but didn't found a solution.

The error: There is no such module 'Firebase'

Does anyone knows the solution?

Comment: Sorry, can;t help you directly but you might want to include the content of the error to give folks more of an idea what's going on.

Comment: Error: No such module 'Firebase' I've already tried to build it but the error stays there.